# How to printscreen on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, image, gui, midori

I would like to screenshot the Midori browser and i've tried the following methods as mentioned [**HERE**](http://yvonnezoe.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/how-to-take-screenshot-on-raspberry-pi/).

1. Using Imagemagick which is pre-installed in Raspberry Pi. I pressed the printscreen key on the keyboard and attempt to paste it on that software. But failed.
2. Open up a new terminal, i typed the following:

   `sleep 5; import -window root myscreen.png` // printscreen after 5 seconds

This is what i got.

[image: imagemagick printscreen]

Type

```
import -window root screen.png
```

This is the black screen that i got.

[image: imagemagick printscreen]

So what is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 13):

There are several programs to take screenshots. I use scrot, a command line utility wich is quite complete. In your case:

`sudo apt-get install scrot`

`scrot -s` and click on the midori window. You will get a timestamp-based png in the working directory of your terminal. See `man scrot` for more options!

Comment: Thank you! +1 it's wonderful! but it took the screenshot of the terminal as well :p

Answer (score 8):

Just use the Print Screen key on your keyboard that will save a PNG image in your home directory (/home/pi) of the whole desktop.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes i did it! thanks to M Noit :)

```
sudo apt-get install scrot
```

then, to take a screenshot after 5 seconds delay, (i got the screen with the terminal in it too! so i need some delays. Also, i can't execute that command through puTTy)[image: screenshot without delay]

```
$ sudo scrot -d5
```

and i get a nice screenshot! :D
[image: screenshot after 5 seconds delay]

Comment: You did not find/propose a new solution for your problem, so your thanks should not be formed as a new answer. Instead it should have been given as a reply to an original answer of a solution provider.

Comment: @avra `$ sudo scrot -d5` this is the exact answer. `thanks` for leading towards finding the solution. ;)

Comment: I just tried Scrot and it worked well. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Best answer with the visuals.  Any way to set up the **PrintScreen key** (aka **PrtScrn** aka **prtsc**) to take a capture?  I got spoiled the way Dropbox does that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here might be that you need to tell imagemagik what screen to take an image of, like so:

```
sleep 5; DISPLAY=":0.0"; export DISPLAY; import -window root filename.png
```

otherwise it will get confused between different X11 sessions (such as using VNC clients)

Personally I tend to take screen shots from another machine using RDP, that way they get saved onto a machine with more disk space and I have more control over what is saved (rather then cropping post-event).

Comment: hmm, it's as black as before. :(